# How to disable Sitecore's embedded language parser

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have a site that has many URL rewrites and a good portion of them contain old links that are prefixed with a country code (e.g. /fr, /de, etc). Rewrites *without* the prefixes work just fine but those with trigger Sitecore's embedded language URL parser which bypasses the rewrite module entirely.

**Example**
*/fr/old-link* tries to parse 'fr' as a language and fails as 'fr-FR' is the name of the French language.

**Solution** I need to disable Sitecore's ability to detect a language prefix in the URL so the URL rewrite module can proceed unhindered.

I can't find where it is in the pipeline that this occurs. I've gone through numerous with Reflector and come up short. I need help please.

Comment: I got some info on StripLanguage and URL resolvement here: http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2014/03/seo-friendly-url-resolver-issue-striplanguage-and-alwaysstriplanguage maybe it can help your case

Comment: Thank you, Ruud, I'll take a look shortly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another pipeline to look at is the preprocessRequest pipeline. It has a StripLanguage processor that detects if the first part of the URL is a language and acts on it.

More info on how to get Sitecore to ignore the language part of the url can be found in this post http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2013/11/sitecore-item-with-language-name.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look shortly :)

Comment: That was the one that was causing the problems. The rewrite module was affecting Sitecore in other ways so I kept the config file an wrote my own pipeline process to intercept the request and match it against any rewrites. Thanks to those who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new LanguageResolver to replace the standard Sitecore one (`Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver`). This is referenced in the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline section in web.config. Here you can handle requests beginning with fr as opposed to fr-FR etc. In the past I have done a similar thing for when we wanted to use non-ISO language codes.

**EDIT**

The `LanguageResolver` resolves language based on query string first, but will also resolve based on file path (i.e. having fr-FR in the start of your path).  I think you would need to inherit from the Sitecore LanguageResolver and override the GetLanguageFromRequest method changing the `else` statement to use something different to `Context.Data.FilePathLanguage` - possibly just using regex/string manipulation to get the first folder from the URL then  use that to set the context language. This should prevent the failure to resolve language which I understand is killing your URL rewrite module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however that was the first processor I looked at but it only deals with the query string parameter method of changing context language, not the prefix before the item path. I need to intercept and 'skip over' that element of the pipeline only, the existing language resolver is fine as is.

Comment: @wardey please see my edits above. Hopefully this addresses your queries.

Comment: I hang my head in shame :) A proper woods-for-the-trees moment here. I've been spinning a lot of plates and must've overlooked it. Thanks much, jumping back onto this now.